# Disable "Add To Compare" button in Magento

Tags: magento, compare

could you help me to disable "Add To Compare" button in magento ?

i want to remove add to compare, when hover the product ?
and this is link of my site : http://dev.kesato.com/lepetitcartel

Answer (score 6):

The links above appear to be for v1.7. However, this worked for me in v1.9:

Open: **app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml** and remove or comment:

```
<?php if($_compareUrl=$this-getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
  <li><span class="separator">|</span> 
  <a  title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?> " href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" rel="tooltip" class="link-compare "><?php echo $this->__('Add toCompare') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Do the same to grid view.

Then, open: **app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml** and remove or comment:

```
<?php
$_compareUrl = $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product);
?>
<?php if($_compareUrl) : ?>
<li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Lastly, open: **app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/layout/catalog.xml** and remove or comment:

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" after="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/></block>
```

Save and clear cache.

Comment: The second step should also be applied to `template/wishlist/item/configure/addto.phtml`

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to disable the wishlist, without the need to touch any code is in the backend: system_config/edit/section/advanced

Configuration / Advanced / Advanced

just find Mage_Wishlist near the bottom of the list and choose disable and Save Config

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to axe the compare products functionality in different places of your site.

> http://www.aschroder.com/2009/07/removing-the-compare-function-in-magento-the-easy-way/
>
> http://inchoo.net/magento/removing-product-comparison-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

> Copy ~/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php  to 
>   ~/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php

and change the following code:

Goto About 165 no Line Just Change as Follow , It May be compeletely remove Compare Option

```
public function getAddUrl($product)
    {
        if ($this->_logCondition->isVisitorLogEnabled() || $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
           return $this->_getUrl('catalog/product_compare/add', $this->_getUrlParams($product));

        }
        return '';
    }
```

Changed To

```
 public function getAddUrl($product)
    {
        if ($this->_logCondition->isVisitorLogEnabled() || $this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            //return $this->_getUrl('catalog/product_compare/add', $this->_getUrlParams($product));
            return false;
        }
        return '';
    }
```

Comment: You Change it on your local not core [/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php], I think all magento developer understand this.Plz Study http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-1.html

Comment: You rewrite core class in local folder. for example you whant update magento for apply update you need rewrite class again because this class update in mage. good practic for this issues install this extensions https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/remove-compare.html If you whant return compare your simple disable modul...

Comment: @Naumov as a magento developer try to create module,Sometime  3rd party free module may crash your sit. if u non developer you may use 3rd party free module to your own responsibility.Here try give real solution different way not provide a 3rd party module link

Comment: Simplest and most effective. This effectively removes compare functionality from everywhere and we don't need to change many files. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All the answers given tell you to remove add to compare button from the product page but this link also comes in the display of all products by category from which we go on particular product page .To remove from that page

```
app/design/frontend/<theme>/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

go to the text

```
<?php
$_compareUrl = $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product);
?>
<?php if($_compareUrl) : ?>
<li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

and comment it out or rather delete it.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Great question and very simple answer

if none of the above solution work try this
just go to the file view.phtml  at location app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

find the block

and block the complete division as:

```
            <!--    <div class="add-to-box add-to-box1">
                    <div class="actions-inner">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                        <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <li>
                                <a class="email-friend fa fa-envelope" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?>" href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><span><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>  
                </div>

                -->
```

it will surely work you can contact me at sagar.career1122@gmail.com

@sagar

Answer (score -1):

I did this and it worked...Using Rindex data
Log into your magento admin, then to go your system, and then INDEX MANAGEMENT, after loading, selec all index and then by your right at the top submit to rindex..the refresh your homepage..OOHLA there you go!!